# custom scrollbar gets loaded but not visible

Tags: jquery

I installed this custom js scrollbar on my webpage http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

I see that the script adds mcustomscrollbar class to the body so im guessing it's not the coding problem.

I used simple jquery markup to get it loaded on html.

```
<script>
  (function($){
$(window).load(function(){
  $("body").mCustomScrollbar({
    theme:"3d-thick",
      scrollInertia: 150,
      axis:"y",
    scrollButtons:{
      enable:true
    }
  });
  $(".board").mCustomScrollbar({
    axis:"y",
    theme:"3d"
  });
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

and here is the problematic page that doesn't load the custom scrollbar.

http://lifeto.cafe24.com/xe/request

can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have forgotten to add 
`<script src="/path/to/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>`at the bottom of your head tag, as it tells you to do.

Comment: i just replaced the <script src="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script> to <script src="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script> but nothing happening.